# how we can implement rejecting the older updates to the redis cache

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I have a scenario where redis put operation is based on kafka messages and consider scenario that one of the put operation with a key is obselete. Already cache got updated with latest value for that key.

ie, a put operation is successfully completed at a specific time 2:50 but previous put operation at 2:49 wasnt completed. So i need to reject put operation happened at 2:49. Is there a way we can handle this in redis

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean with "put operation" in Redis?

Comment: I am using JCache which uses redisson as cache provider and i will perform put operation of JCache for a cache name with key, value pair which will add an entry to redis cache. Since kafka message consumer is invoking this put operation, there are chance that some put operation will be delayed and which becomes outdated. So I need to ignore those put operation if existing cache value is latest and value which is trying to put is outdated one

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is directly handled in Redis in any case. In fact You have to write your own application logic. Try to maintain the kafka message with `{key, value, timestamp}`. Then you can put into this redis with two options

1. `Key --> Value` and `Key -- timestamp`
2. `Key - {"["value","TimeStamp"]}`(Json Format)

Whenever you are doing put operation try to read the last timestamp update for the given key and accordingly update the key value pair in redis.